# XSS possible inside the value field of input tag when double quote is filtered?

Tags: web-application, xss, appsec

Is it possible to get XSS in the value field of Input tag when the application filters out double quote?

```
<input type="hidden" name="something" id="somenthing" value="my_input_goes_here">
```

input from request goes inside the value field , so i tried to close it with `"` and give a payload like `" accesskey="X" onclick="alert(1)"` but `"` is filtered out.

So any XSS vector possible in this scenario?

Comment: Have you tried encoding / double encoding it?

Comment: @Jeroen-ITNerdbox Yes,  both single and double encoding but still it's getting filtered.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, per the HTML specification, only the matching quote (in this case, double quotes), can get you out of the attribute value context.

You might be able to get a `"` past the filter with some filter evasion tricks, but as long as the browser's HTML parser doesn't see a literal double quote, it won't exit the attribute context for you to inject a payload.

Comment: agreed. So is there any event handlers or payload that can be given directly inside the attribute value context itself ? . So that i don't have to use double quote

Comment: No event handlers cannot be specified inside that paramater you will have to break out of the parameter first

Answer (score 0):

No,Only a double quote will be able to get out of that situation. But sometimes developers don't quote a parameter .Then they can be broken out of with various ways including [space] % * + , - / ; < = > ^ and |.Lookup OWASP xss filter evasion cheat sheet to learn more.